# Bookmarklets that work with Frames?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, frames, frameset

Over the next year, I'll be hacking on an off-the-shelf web app from a Major Software Vendor. While we will have access to large portions of the code base, I'll be working blind on some of the web forms. Of course, Major Software Vendor only supports IE 6 & 7. It would be really nice to use some of the bookmarklets I use in more "modern" web development, even when strapped with IE as my development platform:

- [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)
- [jQueryify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet)
- [JASH](http://billyreisinger.com/jash/)
- [Xray](http://www.westciv.com/xray/)

However, none of these tools seem to work with the app in question, due to the fact that it's using *frames*. Does anyone have any tips for getting these (or other) bookmarklets to work when working with frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/tips.asp

Note: One of the links is out of date. This works:

http://web.archive.org/web/20070209124150/http://msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/author/om/xframe_scripting_security.asp

Comment: This doesn't help me immediately, but maybe I can "fork" the bookmarklet code myself and try to tackle the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Javascript Shell bookmarklet for IE](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000287.html).

I've used it with great success in frames. It works well because its interactive javascript console opens in a new window.